# Maximum Data Rate on BLE Dual Mode Device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

Can a Dual Mode BLE device transmit data at the BT (BR or EDR) speeds? I am working on a project that is power sensitive and usually transmits very little data - so BLE makes sense but the device will occasionally need to dump several Megabits of data very quickly so I want to make it switch to standard BT for those high data transmissions. Is this possible?

Comment: Word is that 10-15kbps is about the BLE limit

Answer (score 1):

I can not answer with certainty, but I'm working on a project that uses a BT dual module (cc2564). The module works with both connections BLE and BR/EDR simultaneously and although I have not sent very large amounts of data in BR/EDR mode, I had no problem with transmissions. So my answer is that it is possible that the module (in my case the cc2564) may be working as BLE and can switch to BR/EDR mode to transmisitr large amounts of data.

I wanted to put this answer as a comment, because is not a proven response, but I haven't enough points to make it, and I think that maybe you want to know this. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/low-energy-tech-info.aspx) page seems pretty clear to me that a dual mode chip can function as a classic bluetooth chip.

Therefore it would have the same throughput as a classic bluetooth chip. More on that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy#Technical_details).

However, for your application it sounds like this device is only transmitting data. Therefore you might consider turning the radio completely off between updates. At that point it is largely irrelevant whether you use BLE.